# How does the process of sending data through a socket really work?

Tags: php, c++, qt, sockets, stream

I have written a server/client setup that can send strings back and forth and it works. Now I am trying to send data from a php script which is not working, so I am trying to unravel why exactly it will not work.

This is the code sending data from client, the string I send to server = "aa"

**(mind the comments in the code)**

```
void Client::sendNewMessage(){
    qDebug() << "sendNewMessage()";

    QString string(messageLineEdit->text()); 

    QByteArray block;
    QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);
    out << quint16(0) << string; // why is the quint16 appended before the string?
    out.device()->seek(0); // set current position to 0, why exactly?
    out << (quint16)(block.size() - sizeof(quint16)); // substract 16bit unsigned int from the total data size? 
                                                      //Probably something to do with the appending of the quint16 at the beginning.

    tcpSocket->write(block);
}
```

and this is the read function for the server:

```
void TcpServer::readIncomingData(){
    QDataStream in(tcpServerConnection);
    in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);

    int size = (int) sizeof(quint16); // get packetsize? size = 2 because quint16 is 2 bytes?
    qDebug() << "size = " << size;

    // ** OPTIONAL CODE, WORKS WITHOUT ASWELL ** // I got this somewhere from the internet.
    if (tcpServerConnection->bytesAvailable() < (int)sizeof(quint16))
        return; // if size of packet is less than 2, return. 
                // Because there is not enough bytes to correctly read the data?

    quint16 blockSize = 0;
    in >> blockSize; // i noticed that after this line executes
                     // tcpServerConnection->bytesAvailable is substracted by 2
                     // and blockSize = 8 instead of 10, because 
                     // tcpServerConnection->bytesAvailable starts with 10.
                     // it seems that the socket recognizes that a quint16 was appended
                     // before the actual data, hence the 8 bytes. Is this correct?

    if (tcpServerConnection->bytesAvailable() < blockSize)
        return;

    QString data;
    in >> data;
    qDebug() << "data = " << data;
```

So the main purpose for these questions is to be able to send data from a PHP scripts to the server, so I need (and want) to know how exactly this whole process works. I would be glad if someone could shine some light upon this black hole :D

**NOTE** the server and client are written using QTcpSocket and QTcpServer.

Comment: The sockets are sequential I/O devices and seeking on them is a no-op. Don't seek on them!

Comment: ... but the first seek in your code is valid. You're seeking on a buffer, not a socket :)

Comment: @KubaOber aaah yes, i already got that from the below comments :D Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP is a *byte stream* protocol, which means that data is send and received in an ordered steam of bytes without preserving any logical message boundaries.  In that respect, reading data is a a bit like reading `std::cin` when your terminal's set to unbuffered mode: you might get the next character the user has typed, or 10 characters, or a complete line, a line and a half or the next 4k.  About the only thing you can be sure of is that you can't get more than has been written to the stream.  It's up to you to work out when you've got enough data to process meaningfully: that might be by...

- scanning for a sentinel character like `'\n'`, knowing that complete lines of input are distinct "logical" messages worth processing
- prepending a length for the next logical message, either as a fixed length field (easier) or variable length text followed by a known separator such as space or newline; this is what your code is doing with the 2-byte `quint16` `size` value
- padding each logical message to a fixed length

It's then necessary to keep `read()`ing or `recv()`ing until enough bytes have been read for you to process the next logical message.

It seems your `QDataStream` is making this easier for you by `read()`ing/`recv()`ing whenever it can - perhaps in a background thread or when your app is otherwise idle.  It obviously provides `bytesAvailable()` as a count of the bytes it's already received from the TCP stream and has in its buffer.

On the client side:

```
QString string(messageLineEdit->text()); 
QByteArray block;
QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);
out << quint16(0) << string; // why is the quint16 appended before the string?
```

This writes a 2-byte "0" value followed by the text from `string`.  The former is effectively reserving space for the length of the `string`.

```
out.device()->seek(0); // set current position to 0, why exactly?
```

This skips back before the string to where the 2-byte "0" value was written above...

```
out << (quint16)(block.size() - sizeof(quint16)); // substract 16bit unsigned int from the total data size?
```

This overwrites the "0" value written above with the actual size of the string, which it determines by subtracting 2 bytes from the `block` size.

On the server side, it looks like the function's intended to be called each time more data's received, and will check whether there's enough data to parse as the next message.  It looks buggy though, as if there's enough data to parse out the `size` but the entire string hasn't been buffered yet, then it returns and in doing so discards all knowledge of the `blockSize`, which will already have been removed from the `QDataStream`.  Instead, it should remember that `blockSize` somewhere (e.g. in a class member variable) and the next time the function's called it should continue from `if (tcpServerConnection->bytesAvailable() < blockSize)`.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. So if I am correct, on the server side, "in >> blocksize" only streams 2 bits inside the variable because the variable is of type quint16 which is 2 bits. And the first 2 bits contain the string length which is 8 bytes, hence blocksize = 8 (confirms what i see in debugging). I also did not realize that on clientside, seek(0) puts the stream in the first position and then overwrites the first 2 bytes with the size of the REAL message.

Comment: @CantThinkOfAnything: right idea, though `quint16` is two *bytes*, not bits.  The `seek(0)` thing is silly, given the size of the string must be available to write directly to the file without such shenanigans.

Comment: ah yes indeed, that was a typo. And with the seek bit, you are saying i can append the size of the message first and then the string, instead of appending an empty size unit and then the string and then again the actual size. So basically 2 steps instead of 3. Correct?

Comment: Thanks a lot by the way, again. All this really cleared up my understanding. I am now also able to receive normal strings instead of QString only because i buffer in each char and append it to a QByteArray while there is enough bytes to form a "logical" message. Afterwards i convert the QByteArray to a normal string and it works

Comment: "This skips back before the string to where the 2-byte "0" value was written above..." Since the sockets are sequential, seeking on them makes no sense and is a no-op. This is documented: *Sequential devices don't support seeking to arbitrary positions. The data must be read in one pass. The functions `pos()` and `size()` don't work for sequential devices. `QTcpSocket` and `QProcess` are examples of sequential devices.*

Comment: @KubaOber      Thanks for clearing that up, I also did not know that these were sequential devices

Comment: Alas, of course you're not writing it to a socket, but to a buffer, so what I said about the seek is correct but doesn't apply here. `QBuffer` is **not** a sequential device. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @KubaOber: no worries - I had to look twice to check was the seek was on too.

Comment: @CantThinkOfAnything Yes regarding 2 steps instead of 3 (or 4 if you count write 0 length, write string, seek, write correct length).  And you're welcome.  Don't forget to correct the bug mentioned in the last paragraph - it's the kind of thing that'll be most likely to cause failure when your program's transferring lots of data over slower / less reliable network connections and/or on more loaded/busy machines.  Cheers

Comment: @KubaOber       oh nevermind then hehe, the seek is correct because the QByteArray is the one being written to. After that the socket writes the content of the array. Correct?

Comment: @TonyD         and yes, i will fix that! What you mean is: With a slower network, one big datachuck might be transfered while readyread is called several times (data arrives at different intervals because of the slow connection). And if I don't keep track of the already transfered blocksize, things will go wrong. Correct?

Comment: @CantThinkOfAnything: yes, that's about the way it works... correct.  Cheers